Baby Rudin Theorem 1.19 Step 1
I am studying real analysis from baby Rudin. I have a question regarding Step 1 of the construction of $\mathbb R$ in the proof of Theorem 1.19.

Step 1: The members of $\mathbb{R}$ will be certain subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$, called cuts. A cut is, by definition, any set $\alpha \subset \mathbb{Q}$ with the following three properties.
(I) $\alpha \ne \varnothing$ and $\alpha \ne \mathbb{Q}$
(II) If $p \in \alpha$, $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, and $q < p$, then $q \in \alpha$.
(III) If $p \in \alpha$, then $p <r$ for some $r \in \alpha$.
The letters $p,q,r\cdots$ will always denote rational numbers, and $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \cdots$ will denote cuts.

Then, below this, he says that Property (II) implies two facts:

If $p \in \alpha$ and $q \notin \alpha$ then $p < q$
If $r \notin \alpha$ and $r < s$ then $s \notin \alpha$

How did he obtain those two facts? If we use contrapositive of (II), then we have that $q \notin \alpha$ implies $p \leqslant q.$ I am not sure what's happening with Property (II).

For the first fact, suppose that $p \in \alpha$ and $q \not\in \alpha$.  We have three possibilities: $p < q$, $p=q$, or $p > q$.  We certainly don't have $p = q$ in this case, because one is in $\alpha$ and one isn't, so they can't be the same thing.  Property (II) says that if $p > q$ then $q \in \alpha$, but we know that $q \not\in \alpha$, so that rules out $p > q$.  The only option left is that $p < q$.
For the second fact, suppose that $r \not\in \alpha$ and $r < s$.  If $s \in \alpha$ then Property (II) tells us that $r \in \alpha$ as well; since that isn't true, we must have $s \not\in \alpha$.

Excellent Chris. baby rudin is intellectual gymnastics indeed



The letters $p,q,r\cdots$ will always denote rational numbers, and $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \cdots$ will denote cuts.
(II) If $p \in \alpha$ and $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $q < p$, then $q \in \alpha$.


(i) If $p \in \alpha$ and $q \notin \alpha,$ then $p < q.$
(ii) If $r \notin \alpha$ and $r < s,$ then $s \notin \alpha.$


Property (II) implies that If p∈α and q∉α, then p<q or p=q or q∉Q, which implies Fact (i), because $p\ne q$ (since exactly one of $p$ and $q$ is a member of $\alpha)$ and $q\in\mathbb Q$ (by definition).
Property (II) logically implies that If s∈α and r∈Q and r<s, then r∈α, which logically implies that If r∉α, then s∉α or r∉Q or not r<s, which logically implies that If r∉α and r<s, then s∉α or r∉Q, which implies Fact (ii), because $r\in\mathbb Q$ (by definition).
